# How to put in a proper file path in java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, relative-path, oracle-outside-in

I would like to know how to properly put in a text file and then convert it to an HTML file.

When I try putting a text file I get the errors

`java.security.InvalidParameterException: Configuration file unreadable.
    at com.outsideinsdk.ExportTest.parseConfig(ExportTest.java:51)
    at com.outsideinsdk.ExportTest.<init>(ExportTest.java:35)
    at com.outsideinsdk.ExportTest.main(ExportTest.java:197)`

Sample code below

```
package com.outsideinsdk;


import com.outsideinsdk.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * The <code>ExportTest</code> class tests the {@link Export Export} technology
 * according to the properties provided in a given configuration file.  The
 * configuration file is assumed to be correctly formatted.
 *
 * @author Kevin Glannon
 * @version 1.00
 * @see Export Export
 */
public class ExportTest
{
    private static final String INPUTPATHKEY = "inputpath";
    private static final String OUTPUTPATHKEY = "outputpath";
    private static final String OUTPUTIDKEY = "outputid";

    Properties configProps = new Properties();

    /**
     *  Since <code>ExportTest</code> objects are always associated with a
     *  configuration file, the constructor requires a configuration file path.
     *
     *  @param cfp  The configuration file path.
     */
    public ExportTest(String cfp)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        parseConfig(cfp);
    }

    /**
     *  Parse the configuration file specified by the given path.
     *
     *  @param cfp  The configuration file path.
     */
    public void parseConfig(String cfp)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        //  Assure the configuration file exists and is readable.
        File cff = new File(cfp);

        if (!cff.exists() || !cff.isFile() || !cff.canRead())
        {
            throw(new InvalidParameterException("Configuration file unreadable."));
        }

        BufferedReader cfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(cff));

        String line;
        //  Loop over all lines from the file.
        while ((line = cfr.readLine()) != null)
        {
            processLine(line);
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Support the parsing of the configuration file by processing a given
     *  line.
     *
     *  @param l  A line from a configuration file.
     */
    private void processLine(String l)
    {
        //  Look for comments.
        int indPound = l.indexOf('#');

        //  Remove comments and whitespace.
        String line = (indPound == -1) ? l.trim() :
                                                                         l.substring(0, indPound).trim();

        if (line.length() != 0)
        {
            StringTokenizer stl = new StringTokenizer(line);
                        String key = stl.nextToken();
                        String value = stl.nextToken();
                        while(stl.hasMoreTokens())
                        {
                          value +=" " + stl.nextToken();
                        }
                        //  Fill in the appropriate property.
                        configProps.setProperty(key, value);
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Run the conversion using the given input path, output path.
     *
     *  @param ifp     Input path.
     *  @param ofp     Output path.
     *  @param timeout Export process timeout in milliseconds.
     */
    public void convert(String ifp, String ofp, long timeout)
    {
        String oid = configProps.getProperty(OUTPUTIDKEY);

        //  Display the parameters.
        System.out.println("Input Path: "+ifp+" Output Path: "+ofp+
                                             " Output ID: "+oid);

        //  Remove extra control properties.
        configProps.remove(INPUTPATHKEY);
        configProps.remove(OUTPUTPATHKEY);

        //  Create list of input files.
        File iff = new File(ifp);
        File [] iffa;
        if (iff.isDirectory())
            iffa = iff.listFiles();
        else
        {
            iffa = new File[1];
            iffa[0] = iff;
        }

        //  Create output directory if needed.  Assuming that if the input path
        //  is a directory, the output path should also be a directory.
        File off = new File(ofp);
        if (iff.isDirectory() && !off.exists()) off.mkdir();

        //  Process the conversion.
        Export e = new Export(configProps);
        if (off.isDirectory())
        {
            //  The outputid is in the form fi_XXX where XXX is a reasonable
            //  extension so we take the extension for the oid.
            //  oid.substring(3) means to get the string following the fi_
            String ext = "." + oid.substring(3);
            for (int i=0; i<iffa.length; i++)
            {
                String ifn = iffa[i].toString();
                String ofn = ofp + File.separator + iffa[i].getName() + ext;
                System.out.println("Converting "+ifn+" to "+ofn);
                ExportStatusCode result = e.convert(ifn, ofn, oid, timeout);
            if (result.getCode() == ExportStatusCode.SCCERR_OK.getCode())
            {
                   System.out.println("Conversion Successful!");
            }
            else {
               System.out.println("Conversion Error: " + result);
            }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i=0; i<iffa.length; i++)
            {
                ExportStatusCode result = e.convert(iffa[i].toString(), ofp, oid, timeout);
            if (result.getCode() == ExportStatusCode.SCCERR_OK.getCode())
            {
                   System.out.println("Conversion Successful!");
            }
            else {
               System.out.println("Conversion Error: " + result);
            }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Run the test according to the given arguments.  These arguments must adhere to the following usage.<br><br>
     * Usage:<br>
     * ExportTest InputPath OutputPath ConfigurationFile [Timeout]<br><br>
     *
     * InputPath and OutputPath may be single files or directories.  If InputPath is a directory, then all files in
     * that directory will be converted, but without recursion.  If OutputPath is a directory, then all converted
     * files from InputPath are placed in the OutputPath directory by appending an extension which represents the
     * output file type. Timeout is in milliseconds.
     *
     *  @param args  Command line arguments.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int count = args.length;

        //  Check for specification of configuration file.
        if (count != 3 && count != 4)
        {
            System.out.println("Input path, output path and configuration file are required.");
            System.out.println("Usage: ExportTest InputPath OutputPath "+
                                                 "ConfigurationFile [Timeout(in milliseconds)]");
            System.out.println();
        }
        else
        {
            ExportTest ct = null;

            try
            {
                ct = new ExportTest(args[2]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

            long   timeout = 0;
            if( count == 4 )
            {
                timeout = Integer.decode( args[3] ).longValue();
            }

            ct.convert(args[0], args[1], timeout);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how my program arguments look like: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKF7b.png)

This is where the yes.txt files are located in the project called explorer: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kIaO.png)

Comment: Where is this file? What's the working directory in your Java Application launch? Does the path you're supplying make sense from there? https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-executionArgs.htm

Comment: There may be two issues reading the file: wrong path name or a issue for your App reading the file. If you are on Windows, you may not read files in every directory.

Comment: Still isn't working, please see the pics I included. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: In a case like this, you debug the code, and you have a look what the value of cff looks like when it's read.